# Функция mail(). Для чего отправлять заголовок с письмом "MIME-Version: 1.0"?

Tags: email, php

Нужно ли отправлять заголовок "MIME-Version: 1.0"?

И зачем он нужен?

Как грамотней?

Нужно просто отправлять html письмо без всяких там прикрепленных файлов

```
/* получатели */
$to= "Mary <mary@example.com>" . ", " ; //обратите внимание на запятую
$to .= "Kelly <kelly@example.com>";

/* тема/subject */
$subject = "Birthday Reminders for August";

/* сообщение */
$message = '
<html>
<head>
 <title>Birthday Reminders for August</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Here are the birthdays upcoming in August!</p>
<table>
 <tr>
<th>Person</th><th>Day</th><th>Month</th><th>Year</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Joe</td><td>3rd</td><td>August</td><td>1970</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
<td>Sally</td><td>17th</td><td>August</td><td>1973</td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
';

/* Для отправки HTML-почты вы можете установить шапку Content-type. */
$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

/* дополнительные шапки */
$headers .= "From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com\r\n";

/* и теперь отправим из */
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: @fhgdjdggdj, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если в письме необходимо указать, например, `Content-Type: (text/plain или text/html)` то нужно указывать `mime`. Что такое и зачем нужно mime можно прочитать [здесь](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mail#part_7)

Answer (score 0):

Это стандарт RFC-822. В настоящее время любое отправленное письмо, даже если оно не содержит никаких вложений, так или иначе использует MIME.

MIME-Version является обязательным параметром.
[rfc2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html)