# Артефакты в письме

Tags: php

Отправляю письмо себе на почту. в кодировке utf-8 , и иногда возникают такие артефакты , не могу понять изза чего?

```
$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Вот такие вещи иногда вылазят и все ломают

```
  <t! d>
```

в тегах, в строках , вылазит ! знак

Comment: проверьте кодировку файла .php

Comment: проверил utf 8 без bom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В заголовок необходимо добавить `MIME-Version: 1.0`

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";    
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

[Функция mail(). Для чего отправлять заголовок с письмом "MIME-Version: 1.0"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/128575/)

Comment: не подошло к сожалению, все равно вылазит !

Comment: <td>&lt;td!
 &gt;4333</td>  вот что вылазит. как бы дублируется теги и перешифровуются. при этом в коде генерирующем тело письма, ошибок  нет

Comment: @mydls1 может ошибка в самом HTML?

Comment: 10 строк нормально, 1 с артифактом, там вот такой код

Comment: $insertProductTable .= '<tr>
                                        <td>'.$lastID.'</td>
                                        <td>'.$sku.'</td>
                                        <td>'.$category.'</td>
                                        <td>'.$name.'</td>
                                        <td>'. $manufacturer_name .'</td>
                                        <td>'.$price.'</td>
                                        <td>'.$quantity.'</td>
                                    </tr>';

Comment: обновил ответ, проверьте

Comment: Cпасибо помогло, а не могли бы обьяснить, подробнее об этой проблеме? или ссылку дать

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/128575/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-mail-%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-mime-version-1-0